# Certificate issue in calling https REST service from BPEL Process- SOA SUITE 12.2.1.0.0

Tags: soa, bpel, soa-suite

While calling HTTPS REST service inside BPEL SOA Process, I am getting remote fault with the below error:

> oracle.fabric.common.FabricInvocationException:
>   javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
>   PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
>   unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>   detail:
>   unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I can access the same REST service from basic java REST Client.
Both my WebLogic server and the sample java class (which connects to the web service without error) run on the same machine using same truststore cacerts.

What could be wrong here? Any help appreciated

I have already downloaded the certificates from the browser URL and imported to cacerts

Comment: How do you know they are using the same trust store?  What is location of the JKS configures in your PKICredentialMapper?  If you arent using a Java system flag to override the keystone for your other Java application it is definitely not using the same keystore

Comment: can you import the certificate using em console and try?